# How to override standard new account button using aura component for a particular record type?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I want to override the standard new account button for a particular record type .How can i do that using aura component?

Comment: You can't. After clicking the New button, 2 things happens. First there is the modal for the record type selection and then is the new Action which can be overridden. So the override takes place no matter which record type you chose.

Comment: Probably best to solve this would be to implement the override with the record type selection as part of the aura component and deactivate the record type selection in settings.